# Creating array to hold 1000000 numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote a code in C that read a text file with numbers into memory and the create an 2d int array to store them.

The file has the following format:

```
9
9 5 6 2235 45558 6 5544 56565 2
```

The first number is the size of the array and the second line holds as many numbers as the first line says.
MY problem is that the size of the array can't hold more than ~30.000 numbers. How can I make the following code so I can make the array hold until 1.000.000 numbers? I know that I should use some king of long integer but I couldn't do it.

Heres the code

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 


int is_end(char* input) {
    return *input == 0;
}

int is_separator(char* input) {
    return  *input == '\n' || *input == ' ';
}

char* eat_separators(char* input) {
    while (is_separator(input))
        ++input;

    return input;
}

size_t count_lines(char* input) {

    size_t rows = 1;                


     while (!is_end(input)) {       
         if (is_separator(input)) { 
            ++rows;                 
            input = eat_separators(input);  
        }
        else {
            ++input;                
        }


    }
    return rows;
}

char** get_lines(char* input, size_t number_of_rows) {

    char* from = input;
    size_t length = 0;
    size_t line = 0;
    size_t i;
     char** lines = (char**)malloc(number_of_rows * sizeof(char*));

    do {
        if (is_end(input) || is_separator(input)) {
            lines[line] = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
            for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)

                lines[line][i] = *(from + i);

            lines[line][length] = 0;
            length = 0;
            ++line;
            input = eat_separators(input);
            from = input;

        }
        else { 
            ++length;
            ++input;
        }
    } while (!is_end(input));

    /* 
        lines[line] = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            lines[line][i] = *(from + i);

        lines[line][length] = 0;
        ++line; */


    return lines;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char** lines;           
    size_t size;            
    size_t number_of_rows;
    int count;              
    int* children;          


    FILE *input, *output;   
    char *contents;         
    int fileSize = 0;       
        int i;


    input = fopen("xxx.in", "r");





    long int filepos = 0L;
    fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(input);
    fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    contents = (char*)malloc(fileSize + 1);


    size = fread(contents, 1, fileSize, input);
    contents[size] = 0; 
    fclose(input);  


    number_of_rows = count_lines(contents);


    lines = get_lines(contents, number_of_rows);

    if ((count = atoi(lines[0])) <= 0 || count > 1000000){
            return 1;
    }



    children = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

         if ((children[i] = atoi(lines[i + 1])) <= 0 ) 
            return(-1);
        }
             // a check to see if everything stored in the array
            for(i = 0;i<count;i++)
            {
                    printf(" %d : %d\n", i, children[i]);
            }

    free(children);
    free(lines);



    // This is the end! Oh my dear friend, the end!
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying this on a 16bit platform?

Comment: no why??????????????????

Comment: As in that case `sizeof(char *)` would be 2 and allocating space for ~30.000 of them would be around 64KB ... that could explain why things fail when you get higher ...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios that wouldn't explain why it fails at around ~30.000 already

Comment: Oh I see. I work on Win8 x64 bit with 2 Gb ram.

Comment: And which compiler? You also may want to check what `printf("pointer size is: %d\n", sizeof(char*));` prints, and especially check whether `malloc()` returns `NULL` and bail out with an appropriate message if it does ...

Comment: This code looks horribly convoluted to me. Instead of reading in the whole file before parsing out the numbers, can't you just use `fscanf(input,"%d",...)` to read in each integer sequentially>

Comment: What happens when you exceed ~30,000? You say it doesn't work but what goes wrong? Is there an error message? An access violation?

Comment: yes but  I want the procidure to be done in 1.3 seconds. Compiler is gcc and yes the problem is in sizeof(char*) But why?

Comment: @Dan Alien : No error message neither any message at all! Just the last print command to check what numbers are in the array don't proceed!

Comment: OK.So this is programming 101 advice. If you have an interactive debugger that allows you to step through the program and inspect the contents of variables, do that particularly looking at that `count` variable and what each `malloc(.)` returns (and that it isn't `NULL`. If not insert some `printf(.)`s to do the same thing.

Comment: no interactive debugger Also my program works as I said so the problem isn't permetally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Let me explaint the reason of having only 30.000 number that will give reply to your question?

Basically you are trying to convert the character to ASCII values. Let us take the example of character x whos ASCII value is 120. You are changing the character x with 120, the storage capacity of x is 1 byte but the storage capacity of 120 is 3 bytes. So, basically you have to do memory allocation of 3 times higher the actual value computed as 1 byte is expanding into 3 bytes.

In Your code increase the memory allocation 3 times then your problem would be solved.

Comment: O my god why I haven't thought it. i just did what you said `lines[line] = (char*)malloc((length + 1) * 3);` and it worked!

Comment: Is that what I neede to do or I should use a smaller value?

Comment: Smaller value can be used if you are certain on how many char would appear between 100-127 in your file, unless there is no way